# View Models / Presentation Models

Tags: mvp

Would I be correct in saying that View Models / Presentation Models are screen specific and that you would therefore not expect to share them with other screens?

Comment: Closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939345/wpf-should-a-user-control-have-its-own-viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

If you define "share" as there is a one to one mapping between a screen and a view/presentation model, then yes, it is screen specific.

However, it doesn't imply that there can be no reusable controls/code exist between different view/presentation models.