# Handling a UserControl's DependencyProperty Command

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls, dependency-properties, icommand

I am struggling with getting a WPF UserControl to update one of its DependencyProperty when a DependencyProperty **Command** is invoked.

Here's a an example that can hopefully demonstrate what I am trying to achieve. Basically it's a user control with a button on it. When the button is clicked, I'd like to increment an integer (`MyValue`) using a command (`MyCommand`):

**User Control**

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl1"
             x:Name="root"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="100"
             d:DesignWidth="200">

    <Button x:Name="MyButton"
            Content="{Binding MyValue, ElementName=root}"
            Command="{Binding MyCommand, ElementName=root}" />

</UserControl>
```

The **Code-behind** looks like this so far:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Public Class UserControl1
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Public Shared ReadOnly ValueProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyValue", GetType(Integer), GetType(UserControl1), New PropertyMetadata(1))
    Public Shared ReadOnly CommandProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyCommand", GetType(ICommand), GetType(UserControl1))

    Public Property Value() As Integer
        Get
            Return GetValue(ValueProperty)
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            SetValue(ValueProperty, value)
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"))
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Command() As ICommand
        Get
            Return CType(GetValue(CommandProperty), ICommand)
        End Get
        Set(value As ICommand)
            SetValue(CommandProperty, value)
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("Command"))
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Finally, I've added 5 instances of this control to a **Window**:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="450"
        Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <local:UserControl1 Width="40"
                                Height="40" />
            <local:UserControl1 Width="40"
                                Height="40" />
            <local:UserControl1 Width="40"
                                Height="40" />
            <local:UserControl1 Width="40"
                                Height="40" />
            <local:UserControl1 Width="40"
                                Height="40" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

What I would like to do is have each control increment its `MyValue` by 1 when the button is clicked. I've bound the Button's command to `MyCommand` to do so but I do not know where/how to add code to handle the Command invocation.

**What I have tried so far**

I can simply handle the Click event on the button:

```
Private Sub HandleButtonClick() Handles MyButton.Click
    Value += 1
End Sub
```

This works fine but I would like to handle this through the MyCommand binding in an effort to limit code-behind to a minimum.

Another approach I have tried is to create a Command (not as DependencyProperty):

```
Public Shared Property DirectCommand As ICommand

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    DirectCommand = New RelayCommand(Sub() Value += 1)

End Sub
```

(`RelayCommand` class not shown - it's a standard implementation of a delegate command)

This last approach works but since the command is Shared it affects other instances of this user control. For example, if I have 5 instances, clicking 3rd instance will will increment the MyValue on the previous (2nd) instance in the XAML (but not other instances).

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

---

**EDIT 1: Going further with non-DP Commands**

Following @peter-duniho's advice, I continued down the path of using RelayCommands to handle the button click but I am having no luck getting the button to invoke a command that isn't marked as Shared:

```
Public Class UserControl1
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Public Shared ReadOnly ValueProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyValue", GetType(Integer), GetType(UserControl1), New PropertyMetadata(1))
    Private _localValue As Integer = 2

    Public Shared Property IncrementValueCommand As ICommand
    Public Shared Property IncrementLocalValueCommand As ICommand

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        IncrementValueCommand = New RelayCommand(Sub() Value += 1)
        IncrementLocalValueCommand = New RelayCommand(Sub() LocalValue += 1)

    End Sub

    Public Property Value() As Integer
        Get
            Return GetValue(ValueProperty)
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            SetValue(ValueProperty, value)
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"))
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property LocalValue() As Integer
        Get
            Return _localValue
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            If _localValue <> value Then
                _localValue = value
                RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("LocalValue"))
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

I've added a LocalValue to try doing this with no DependencyProperties so I now have two buttons to test both side-by-side:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl1"
             x:Name="root"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="100"
             d:DesignWidth="200">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Row="0"
                Background="DodgerBlue"
                Content="{Binding Value, ElementName=root}"
                Command="{Binding IncrementValueCommand, ElementName=root}" />

        <Button Grid.Row="1"
                Background="Gold"
                Content="{Binding LocalValue, ElementName=root}"
                Command="{Binding IncrementLocalValueCommand, ElementName=root}" />

    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

Using **Shared** commands, both values increment but the result is shown in the user control above the one clicked.

If I remove Shared in my declarations, the values don't update anymore:

```
Public Property IncrementValueCommand As ICommand
Public Property IncrementLocalValueCommand As ICommand
```

This is where I am stuck with this approach. If this can be explained to me I would be very grateful.

As far as creating a **View Model** to handle the User Control's logic, that would be great, I stayed away from that because, from what I have read, it's "code stink" so I was trying to stay away from that approach.

To elaborate a little on my goal: I am trying to make a Label user control that can display two Up/Down controls, one for small increments and one for larger increments. The Label will have many other features like:

1. Flash when data changes
2. Support "scrubbing" (hold and move mouse to increment/decrement value)
3. Have a Highlighted property that changes the label's background color.

The View Model approach seems to make perfect sense to contain all this logic.

Comment: I would never describe the use of a view model in WPF as "code smell" (or "stink", as you put it :) ). It is true that a user control ought to expose publicly-visible data via dependency properties, so that client code can use their own view models to control those values. And the user control should never set its own `DataContext` property, as the client code needs to have that available...again, so it can use its own view model. But, for state that is controlled entirely internally to the user control, a view model may well be perfectly appropriate.

Comment: As far as the new implementation attempt, I've addressed the bugs in that code in comments below my answer. These issues seem like new questions to me though...please don't chain new questions onto an existing one. Feel free to post a new question, as you run into new problems you're unable to figure out yourself. Of course, make sure you've reviewed and understand all the advice you've already received in your existing question(s). Often, you'll find that advice renders the new issues moot, as you'll change your design to fit the better practices.

Comment: As you suggested I have boiled things down and created a new question. Regarding code smell, it was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939345/wpf-should-a-user-control-have-its-own-viewmodel) that made me stay away from creating a View Model for my User Control. Nice to see you're the top comment on that post. As it must be clear I am new to WPF and I am trying to learn how to do things the right way.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the link to the other answer. I see where that would be confusing. Indeed, while I agree with the motivation behind that answer, unfortunately it paints with too broad a brush. I've added [a new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58070227/3538012) to that same question, which I hope will provide a little more clarity.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I ran into [this other answer](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1172579/Viewmodel-for-usercontrol) from Code Project - "for those who code" - about VMs for user controls. Sounds like many people have seen that "code smell" answer.

Comment: The code posted at that link does in fact violate the basic rule that the user control should not alter its own `DataContext`. If they had assigned the context of a child element within the user control, that would be fine, but the code as it stands there is a violation of "generally accepted practices". As for the "code smell" answer, well...for a C#/.NET Q&A, it has a very high number of views and votes, so it stands to reason it would show up as a reference in a variety of places.

Comment: @PeterDuniho So if the client sets a DataContext on the user control (`MyDiskTools.UserControls.NodeGrid.NodeGrid`), the context that had been set in the constructor (`DataContext = new NodeGridVM();`) is replaced and all the bindings in the XAML (`<Setter Property="Padding" Value="{Binding ButtonPadding, FallbackValue=5}"/>` for example) won't work anymore? The DataContext should be set on the `Grid` instead and things would smell better?

Comment: Yes, if the view model is made the context of the inner `Grid` rather than the actual user control, that should be fine. Obviously that person "Will" would likely disagree, but I am not so dogmatic. A view model that is _completely_ an implementation detail, such that the client code is not and cannot be affected by it, should be fine. There are limited scenarios where something that would be useful, but there's no reason to rule it out, and one should feel free to do it that way when appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last attempt is very close to a workable solution. It would have worked, had you simply not made the property a `Shared` property. Indeed, you could have even just assigned the `RelayCommand` instance to the existing `MyCommand` dependency property instead of creating a new property.

That said, it's not clear what you would gain from such an approach. The user control wouldn't wind up being general-purpose, and you could implement that approach with a much-simpler-to-implement event handler for the `Button` element's `Click` event. So, here are some other thoughts with respect to your question and the code contained within…

First, it is very unusual for a WPF dependency object to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and even more unusual for it do so for its dependency properties. Should one decide to do so, instead of doing as you have here, by raising the event from the property setter itself, you *must* instead include a property-change callback when you register the dependency property, like so:

```vb
Public Shared ReadOnly CommandProperty As DependencyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MyCommand", GetType(ICommand), GetType(UserControl1), New PropertyMetadata(AddressOf OnCommandPropertyChanged))

Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Private Sub _RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
End Sub

Private Shared Sub OnCommandPropertyChanged(d As DependencyObject, e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    Dim userControl As UserControl1 = CType(d, UserControl1)

    userControl._RaisePropertyChanged(e.Property.Name)
End Sub
```

The WPF binding system typically updates a dependency property value directly, without going through the property setter. In the code you posted, this means that the `PropertyChanged` event would not be raised with the property is updated via a binding. Instead, you need to do it as above, to make sure that *any* change to the property will result in the `PropertyChanged` event being raised.

That said, I'd advise not implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` for dependency objects. The scenarios where one would make a dependency object are generally mutually exclusive with needing to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, because dependency objects are typically the target of a binding, while `INotifyPropertyChanged` is used for objects which are the source of a binding. The only component that needs to observe the change of a property value in the target of a binding is the WPF binding system, and it can do that without the dependency object implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Second, a more idiomatic way to implement something as you've intended to do here would be to have a separate view model object where the actual value and command would be stored, and bind that view model's properties to the dependency object's properties. In that case, one would have a view model object that looks something like this:

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Class UserControlViewModel
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private _value As Integer

    Public Property Value() As Integer
        Get
            Return _value
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _UpdatePropertyField(_value, value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _command As ICommand

    Public Property Command() As ICommand
        Get
            Return _command
        End Get
        Set(value As ICommand)
            _UpdatePropertyField(_command, value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        Command = New RelayCommand(Sub() Value += 1)
    End Sub

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private Sub _UpdatePropertyField(Of T)(ByRef field As T, newValue As T, <CallerMemberName> Optional propertyName As String = Nothing)
        If Not EqualityComparer(Of T).Default.Equals(field, newValue) Then
            field = newValue
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

(Note: this class includes an `_UpdatePropertyField()` method which handles the actual property change mechanism. Typically, one would actually put this method into a base class, so you can reuse that logic in any view model object one might write.)

In the example above, the view model sets its own `Command` property to the `RelayCommand` object. If this is the only intended scenario one wants to support, then one could just make the property read-only. With the implementation above, one also has the option of replacing the default `ICommand` value with some other `ICommand` object of choice (either a different `RelayCommand` or any other implementation of `ICommand`).

With this view model object defined, one can then give each user control its own view model as a data context, binding the view model's properties to the user control's dependency properties:

```xml
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestSO58052597CommandProperty"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
  <StackPanel>
    <l:UserControl1 Width="40" Height="40" MyValue="{Binding Value}" MyCommand="{Binding Command}">
      <l:UserControl1.DataContext>
        <l:UserControlViewModel Value="1"/>
      </l:UserControl1.DataContext>
    </l:UserControl1>
    <l:UserControl1 Width="40" Height="40" MyValue="{Binding Value}" MyCommand="{Binding Command}">
      <l:UserControl1.DataContext>
        <l:UserControlViewModel Value="1"/>
      </l:UserControl1.DataContext>
    </l:UserControl1>
    <l:UserControl1 Width="40" Height="40" MyValue="{Binding Value}" MyCommand="{Binding Command}">
      <l:UserControl1.DataContext>
        <l:UserControlViewModel Value="1"/>
      </l:UserControl1.DataContext>
    </l:UserControl1>
    <l:UserControl1 Width="40" Height="40" MyValue="{Binding Value}" MyCommand="{Binding Command}">
      <l:UserControl1.DataContext>
        <l:UserControlViewModel Value="1"/>
      </l:UserControl1.DataContext>
    </l:UserControl1>
    <l:UserControl1 Width="40" Height="40" MyValue="{Binding Value}" MyCommand="{Binding Command}">
      <l:UserControl1.DataContext>
        <l:UserControlViewModel Value="1"/>
      </l:UserControl1.DataContext>
    </l:UserControl1>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Each user control object gets its own view model object, initialized the XAML as the `DataContext` property value. Then the `{Binding Value}` and `{Binding Command}` markup cause the view model properties to serve as the source for the dependency property targets for each user control object.

This is a little more idiomatic for WPF. However, it's actually still not really how one would typically go about doing this, because all the view models are hard-coded for the user control objects. When one has a collection of source objects, and wants to represent them visually, one would typically maintain a separation between data and UI through the use of templating and the `ItemsControl` UI element. For example:

```xml
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestSO58052597CommandProperty"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
  <Window.Resources>
    <x:Array x:Key="data" Type="{x:Type l:UserControlViewModel}">
      <l:UserControlViewModel Value="1"/>
      <l:UserControlViewModel Value="1"/>
      <l:UserControlViewModel Value="1"/>
      <l:UserControlViewModel Value="1"/>
      <l:UserControlViewModel Value="1"/>
    </x:Array>
  </Window.Resources>
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource data}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:UserControlViewModel}">
        <l:UserControl1 Width="40" Height="40" MyValue="{Binding Value}" MyCommand="{Binding Command}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

Here, the `StackPanel` which was previously installed explicitly as an element in the window, is now used as the template for the panel in an `ItemsControl` element. The data itself is now stored separately. In this example, I've just used a simple array resource, but in a more realistic program this would often be a collection referenced by a top-level view model used as the data context for the window. Either way, the collection gets used as the `ItemsSource` property value in the `ItemsControl`.

(Note: for static collections as here, an array suffices. But the `ObservableCollection<T>` class is very commonly used in WPF, to provide a binding source for collections that may be modified during the execution of the program.)

The `ItemsControl` object then uses the data template provided in for the `ItemTemplate` property to visually present the view model object.

In this example, the data template is unique for that `ItemsControl` object. It might be desirable to provide a different data template elsewhere, either in a different `ItemsControl`, or when presenting the view model objects individually (e.g. via `ContentControl`). This approach works well for those kinds of scenarios.

But, it is also possible that one might have a standard visualization for the view model object. In that case, one can define a default template to use, placing that in a resource dictionary somewhere, so that WPF can automatically find it in any context where one might be using the view model object as the data context. Then, no template needs to be specified explicitly in the UI elements where that's the case.

That would look something like this:

```xml
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestSO58052597CommandProperty"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
  <Window.Resources>
    <x:Array x:Key="data" Type="{x:Type l:UserControlViewModel}">
      <l:UserControlViewModel Value="1"/>
      <l:UserControlViewModel Value="1"/>
      <l:UserControlViewModel Value="1"/>
      <l:UserControlViewModel Value="1"/>
      <l:UserControlViewModel Value="1"/>
    </x:Array>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:UserControlViewModel}">
      <l:UserControl1 Width="40" Height="40" MyValue="{Binding Value}" MyCommand="{Binding Command}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource data}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

This just barely scratches the surface on topics in WPF like dependency properties, data binding, templating, etc. Some key points in my view to keep in mind are:

1. Dependency objects are generally the target of bindings
2. Data should be independent of visualization
3. **Don't repeat yourself.**

That last one is a crucial point in all programming, and is at the heart of OOP, and even simpler scenarios where you can make reusable data structures and functions. But in frameworks like WPF, there is a whole new range of dimensions in which there's the opportunity for reusing your code. If you find yourself copy/pasting anything related to your program, you're probably violating this very important principle. :)

Comment: A thousand thanks for your answer. I need to digest all you wrote but wanted to immediately thank you. Learning WPF has been as much fun as frustration but this kind of help will surely point me in the right direction!

Comment: Gave the non-DP command approach another shot and without the Shared keyword  the command doesn't seem to execute. I've edited the question to show what I tried.  Seems like it should work but it doesn't.

Comment: You have at least a couple of problems with your code, which together prevent your new attempt from working. **First:** you are not using the same name when you register the property, as the name for the property itself. You _must_ be consistent when dealing with dependency properties (or anything, really). For registering dependency properties -- and anywhere else in code you want a string value that contains the name of some code member -- you should always use `NameOf()`, rather than hard-coding the string. This will ensure consistency, as well as keep things correct after renaming a member

Comment: **Second:** you have declared a read-only property, but initialized it after calling `InitializeComponent()`. The `InitializeComponent()` call will initialize the component (of course) and this includes copying binding source values to their targets. Because the property is read-only, it cannot provide property-change notification, so the target only ever gets the original value (which is `Nothing`). You could make the property work by moving its assignment to occur before the call to `InitializeComponent()`.

Comment: Beyond that, some unsolicited advice: **1)** when you are working to solve a problem, don't complicate things by introducing new behaviors before you've solved the original problem. If anything, you should be working to _simplify_ the scenario, to the bare minimum you think should work. **2)** Never initialize `Shared` members in an instance constructor. This is just _always_ wrong. The only constructor where you should initialize a `Shared` member is the `Shared` constructor (i.e. `Shared Sub New()`). ...

Comment: ... **3)** When posting a question to Stack Overflow or similar forum, generalize your problem as much as possible. You've added a lot of new context to your question, at the end, describing the future goal. These goals are good, but don't seem relevant to the question at hand, and serve only to distract from the core issues you are trying to learn with this question. It's much better to focus on the one thing at a time, and then post a new question if you run into a new problem while trying to apply what you've learned here to your broader goal.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I understand that declaring my commands as Shared doesn't make sense, I kept those because I was getting some movement at least. My last edit was an attempt to zero-in on that issue which I feel will ultimately be the solution to my problem. I think if anyone is in the same boat I was in when posting the question, the answer you provided and the comments to the edits will help them as they are helping me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199859/discussion-between-etienne-laneville-and-peter-duniho).