# UserControl Command to modify Property

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, wpf-controls

In a User Control, I am trying to get a Command to modify a Property. I have an `IncrementValueCommand` and a `Value` property that I want to increment when a button is clicked. The button's `Command` is bound to the `IncrementValueCommand` and the `Content` is bound to the `Value` property.

I have tried two approaches to do this and in both cases the Button doesn't show the Value incrementing..

**1st Approach: Dependency Property for Value**

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl1"
             x:Name="root"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="100"
             d:DesignWidth="200"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

    <Button Content="{Binding Path=Value}"
            Command="{Binding Path=IncrementValueCommand}" />

</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
Public Class UserControl1

    Public Shared ValueProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", GetType(Integer), GetType(UserControl1), New PropertyMetadata(1))

    Public Property IncrementValueCommand As ICommand

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        IncrementValueCommand = New RelayCommand(AddressOf IncrementValue)

    End Sub

    Public Property Value() As Integer
        Get
            Return GetValue(ValueProperty)
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            SetValue(ValueProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub IncrementValue()
        Value += 1
    End Sub

End Class
```

**2nd approach: INotifyPropertyChanged for Value**

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl2"
             x:Name="root"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="100"
             d:DesignWidth="200"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

    <Button Content="{Binding Path=Value}"
            Command="{Binding Path=IncrementValueCommand}" />

</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Class UserControl2
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private _value As Integer = 1
    Public Property IncrementValueCommand As ICommand

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        IncrementValueCommand = New RelayCommand(AddressOf IncrementValue)

    End Sub

    Public Property Value() As Integer
        Get
            Return _value
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            If _value <> value Then
                _value = value
                NotifyPropertyChanged()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    ' This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.  
    ' The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName  
    ' parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.  
    Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(<CallerMemberName()> Optional ByVal propertyName As String = Nothing)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub

    Private Sub IncrementValue()
        Value += 1
    End Sub

End Class
```

I left out the RelayCommand class which is a standard implementation for ICommand.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

---

**Working Code** (thanks to Peter Duniho for his answer)

Adjust the code-behind constructor by creating the `IncrementValueCommand` first:

```
Public Sub New()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call? Nah
    IncrementValueCommand = New RelayCommand(AddressOf IncrementValue)

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

End Sub
```

Comment: You're missing a big part, setting the `DataContext`...

Comment: I am trying to have it uses itself (the user control) as the DataContext. I adjusted the XAML with `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` but it hasn't made a difference so far.

Comment: Try removing `ElementName=root` these.

Comment: I tried that on both now, still nothing. XAML for `UserControl1` in question has been updated to reflect this.

Comment: I think ElementName made it unnecessary to specify a DataContext in this case. Everything is working as desired after following @peter-duniho's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've explained [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58052597/handling-a-usercontrols-dependencyproperty-command?noredirect=1#comment102509852_58055199), the problem in this particular variant of your attempts to use a command to update a value is that you are initializing the `IncrementValueCommand` property *after* the call to `InitializeComponent()` in the class constructor.

The `InitializeComponent()` call is where the binding to that property is set up, i.e. `Command="{Binding Path=IncrementValueCommand}"` in your XAML. When that call is made, the property still has its default value of `null`.

When you assign the property a value later, because the property is an auto-implemented property, there's nothing about that assignment that would cause a property-change notification to happen, so the binding is never updated to reflect the new value.

You can either implement property-change notification for that property, just as is already done for the `Value` property, or you can (as I had suggested earlier) move the assignment within the constructor so that it occurs *before* the call to `InitializeComponent` instead of after.

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot for all your help with this. You've clarified a lot of things.
One note is that when you type `Sub New()`, Visual Studio adds `InitializeComponent` for you and leads you to believe you should be typing your code underneath, especially with the comment it adds: `' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.` Also, in this question, nothing is read-only.

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville: Yes, the IDE is a bit less than helpful in this case, but in its defense, in WPF it's expected that all properties will include property-change notification, so usually it doesn't matter where the property is set. As for this: _" in this question, nothing is read-only"_ -- ah, that's right. 99.94% of my .NET work is done in C#, and I've mis-read the auto-implemented property in VB.NET. I forgot that you don't have to declare the setter in such cases for it to exist.