# DependencyProperty does not work if the value is from a binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, dependency-properties

I created UserControl with viewmodel. It has DependencyProperty which only works if the value is passed directly. If the value is passed through the binding, it no longer works.

Here is the view code:

This is a closed element not associated with any other. All listed items belong to him. This is a code shortening, I am not going to present whole, immeasurable structures.

**View**

```
public partial class SomeView : UserControl
{
    public SomeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetBinding(ActiveProperty, new Binding(nameof(SomeViewModel.Active)) { Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource });
    }

    #region ActiveProperty
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ActiveProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Active), typeof(bool), typeof(VNCBoxView));

    public bool Active
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ActiveProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ActiveProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**VievModel**

```
public class SomeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool active;

    public bool Active
    {
        get { return active; }
        set
        {
            active = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Active)));
        }
    }
}
```

**UserControl**

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModels:SomeViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Active}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

===================================================

When working with a ready component, which is an individual, separate entity, the problem occurs depending on how it is used.
I remind you that the elements used in the view in question are a closed whole that does not connect with the element in which it is used. It is the transfer of value that is the matter of the problem.

**This is working usage:**

```
<local:SomeView Active="True" />
```

In viewmodel, the setter is invoked twice, once with false and then with true.

**If the value comes from binding, it doesn't work:**

```
<local:SomeView Active="{Binding SomeParentProperty}" />
```

In viewmodel, setter is only called once with the value false.

Setters in a view are never called, in both cases.

Please help

Comment: Setting the DataContext of the UserControl breaks the inheritance . Where is `IsConnected` defined and why are you using the `SomeViewModel`?

Comment: @Clemens, please read the problem carefully. It does not duplicate these cases. What they are talking about works perfectly. Nobody there had a problem of binding at the place of use.

Comment: You may also want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28815689/1136211

Comment: And in case "Setters in a view are never called" means that the `set` method of the Active property of your UserControl isn't called: that's because WPF bypasses it and directly calls `SetValue(ActiveProperty, ...)`. You'll need to register a PropertyChangedCallback in order to get notified when a dependency property changes.

Comment: @Clemens, you're talking about things that I know, focusing on completely different issues than those that are the problem. The presence of viewmodel does not matter either. PropertyChangedCallback is only invoked if the value is given directly and this is a problem. Everything or nothing works.

Comment: Well, remove the private view model, especially the DataContext assignment. It is the source of all your trouble. Bind to the UserControl's properties by RelativeSource Bindings. Controls never have private view models. Do you understand that when you write `Active="{Binding IsConnected}"` the IsConnected property is expected to be in the current DataContext object, which you have set to an instance of SomeViewModel? That object just doesn't have that property. Take a look at the Output Window in Visual Studio. You'll notice a corresponding data binding error message.

Comment: Although two people told you about this fact, you seemingly didn't even try it. And there are a lot of similar questions here in StackOverflow, where the answer is always the same. Do not assign a UserControl's DataContext from its XAML or code behind, i.e. do not create a private view model.

Comment: If I do this, it may work somehow, but I won't have a viewmodel useful for me, DataContext will be null, and the view preview will not work...

Comment: As said, controls don't have view models. They handle changes of their properties in their code behind, e.g. in PropertyChangedCallbacks of their dependency properties. If you take a look at the WPF sources, you won't find a single control with a private view model. Anyway, if you insist in having it, a quick hack would be to assign it to the top level Grid in your UserControl's XAML, instead of the UserControl itself.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `IsConnected` property in the `SomeViewModel` instance in the current DataContext of the UserControl, hence the Binding

```
<local:SomeView Active="{Binding IsConnected}" />
```

won't work. It tries to resolve the PropertyPath against the current DataContext, unless you explicitly specify its `Source`, `RelativeSource` or `ElementName`.

This is the exact reason why UserControls should *never* explicitly set their own DataContext, and hence never have something like an own, private view model.

The elements in the UserControl's XAML would not bind to properties of such a private view model object, but directly to the properties of the UserControl, for example like

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Active,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

Comment: Typo? Should be `{Binding Active}`?

Comment: @Sinatr No, as shown in the question. OP seems to have an "external"  view model with that property.

Comment: "IsConnected" is a parent's property, because we're talking about using SomeView, not its content!

Comment: @T.Czubaszek What parent? You haven't shown anything like that in your question, so we can only assume that there is an "outer" view model - with the IsConnected property - in the DataContext of a parent element of SomeView, e.g. a Window or Page.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the `DataContext` explicitly in the `UserControl` like this:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModels:SomeViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

...you can no longer bind to `SomeView`'s `DataContext` in the consuming view like this:

```
<local:SomeView Active="{Binding IsConnected}" />
```

...because `SomeViewModel` doesn't have any `IsConnected` property.

You should avoid setting the `DataContext` explicitly and let the `UserControl` inherit its `DataContext` from its parent element. You can still bind to the dependency property of the `UserControl` itself using a `RelativeSource` or an `ElementName`:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Active, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Besides, `SomeViewModel` seems superfluous in your example since the `UserControl` already has an `Active` property.

Comment: "IsConnected" is a parent's property, because we're talking about using SomeView, not its content!

Comment: `IsConnected` is a property of the `DataContect` of the `<local:SomeView>` element. What's your point? I am binding `Active` to `IsConnected` in this example.