# x:Bind in child user controls

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

In WPF I use the following pattern sometimes:

```
public class InnerViewModel {
  public int I {get ;set;}
}

public class OuterViewModel {
  public InnerViewModel Inner { get; } = new InnerViewModel();
}
```

Outer view:

```
<UserControl x:Class="OuterView" ...>
  <local:InnerView DataContext="{Binding Inner}"/>
</UserControl>
```

Inner view:

```
<UserControl x:Class="InnerView" ...>
  <TextBox Value="{Binding I}"/>
</UserControl>
```

In WinUI 3 I can use `x:Bind` instead of `Binding`. That comes often with a `ViewModel` property in the code behind file of the view:

```
public sealed partial class OuterView : UserControl {
    public OuterViewModel ViewModel {
        get;
    }
    public OuterView() {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.ViewModel = App.GetRequiredService<OuterViewModel>(); 
    }
}
```

and

```
<UserControl x:Class="OuterView" ...>
  <local:InnerView DataContext="{x:Bind Inner}"/>
</UserControl>
```

But for `InnerView` I cannot use `x:Bind`, since it does not work with `DataContext`.
Is there any way to initialized something like a `ViewModel`-property of the  `InnerView` in a similar way as the `DataContext`-binding? Or is it just not possible to apply this pattern to the `x:Bind`-approach?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out: `x:Bind` works also with non-dependency properties, so I can do the following:

```
public sealed partial class InnerView : UserControl {
    public InnerViewModel? ViewModel {
        get; set;
    }
    public InnerView() {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

```
<UserControl x:Class="OuterView" ...>
  <local:InnerView ViewModel="{x:Bind Inner}"/>
</UserControl>
```

and

```
<UserControl x:Class="InnerView" ...>
  <TextBox Value="{x:Bind ViewModel.I}"/>
</UserControl>
```

`InnerView.ViewModel` is not initialized in the constructor, so it needs a setter, but it seems to work.

Comment: I'm not saying that [UserControls shouldn't have ViewModels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939345/should-a-user-control-have-its-own-view-model), but does ``OuterControl`` and ``InnerControl`` really need their own ViewModels? Are you planning to make tests for those ViewModels? If not, I'd implement them in code-behind.

Comment: In my actual code I use the inner view at two places, that is why I separated the xaml-code in its own control.