In WPF, is there a way to declare the type of an ancestor's DataContext?
In a user control I am using the RelativeSource to bind to the command of the DataContext of the hosting window. I have used the d:DataContext to specify the type of the DataContext in both the User Control and the hosting window.
In the Command Binding I could specify the type of the hosting window using AncerstorType, but I can't see any way to specify the type of its DataContext. It would be nice to have a design time warning in case the property of that DataContext is mistyped or do not exist, and to eliminate the squiggly blue underlines.

The DataContext of the parent Window should be inherited by the UserControl, which happens automatically unless you explicitly set the UserControl's DataContext to something else. Explicitly setting a UserControl's DataContext (in its XAML or code behind) is a common programming error, as it breaks the way how standard data binding work.

To add to Clemens' comment: this means that you have to design the control codes in a way that it is completely DataContext agnostic. You achieve this by introducing a dependency property for each external data you need. This was the client of your control can use any DataContex type he wants. He only has to bind it's properties to the controls properties to provide the data. The same way you bind a collection to the ItemsControl ItemsSource property or a string to TextBloxk.Text. These controls are highly reusable because they don't know their DataContext.

So the solution to your problem is to design the control properly as described.

I'm sorry but I don't see why it's a programming error to override the DataContext, unless I'm misusing the UserControl. The way I like to design it, the UserControl is a view, and associated with it is a View Model that controls the interactions. I set the DataContext of the UserControl (the view) to the ViewModel that controls it. I see that as a clean separation. Is that wrong? If so, why?

"In a user control I am using the RelativeSource to bind to the command of the DataContext of the hosting window" - this is not correct approach. user control should not make assumptions about hosting window or its datacontext. instead you can declare a DP of type ICommand in the usercontrol and bind that property on the instance in the window

@PatriceBG You may do some research on StackOverflow about UserControls (or any other controls) with private view models, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939345/should-a-user-control-have-its-own-view-model/28815689#28815689. Control logic typically resides in the code behind of the control, not in a private view model. If you still want to separate the control logic into a private view model, do not set the DataContext of the UserControl, but simply that of the top level element in its XAML. Thus the standard value inheritance of the DataContext property would still work.

Besides that, it is still wrong that a control is aware of the type of its parent. That is a serious design error.

@Clemens "Besides that, it is still wrong that a control is aware of the type of its parent." I thought the opposite was the whole purpose of the MVVM pattern. The view should know of the View Model, but the View Model should not know about the view. And putting code in the code behind should be avoided.
Also, not all controls are general purpose. Some are very specialized and only meant to work on a specific context.

There seem to be two misconceptions on your side. First, the fact that a control must not be aware of its parent element has nothing to with MVVM. A control should just not know anything about the user interface context in which is used. As already said, it should expose bindable properties that control its visual appearance and behavior.

Second, MVVM does not mean no code behind. This is a common misconception, but blatantly wrong. MVVM is about separation of concerns, which means that view logic could be implemented without knowledge of a specific view that uses a view model. This has nothing to with the implementation of a control. Look at the source code of the various controls in WPF. None of them, even the most complex ones, have private view models.

It is not even clear if we are talking about the same thing here, since we haven't seen a single line of your code. This discussion is based on the assumption that your control internally sets its DataContext to a private view model. Is that true? If yes, you are on the wrong track. Creating a UserControl with knowledge of a specific view model (or more precisely a DataContext with a specific set of properties) is a different story. That would be a typical MVVM approach.

However, the control must still not use a private instance of such a view model. The view model would be provided by value inheritance of the DataContext property, i.e. from the parent element of the control.

No, the User Control does not set it's DataContext internally. The DataContext of the UserControl is bound in XAML in the host window.  I have a collection of View Models in the host window and the UserControl is the UI to interact with the selected element in that collection. There are commands however that must be executed in the context of the host window because they potentially affect other elements in the collection that's why I bound a command form the host window to a button in the User Control. I don't see anything wrong with that design.

This is getting to be a religious discussion which is not what I intended. If there is no way to declare the type of the DataContext of an ancestor in XAML, then so be it. I'll live with the squiggly underlines.

@PatriceBG The DataTemplates have a "DataType" property. I use that; as well as the "DataContext DesignInstance Type" declarations extensively. I have "user controls" with up to 6 syncronized ListViews that all have a different "source"; i.e. a different "data context" and "type" for the list view item DataTemplates. We're not all religious.

@Gerry Schmitz Yes, I use the DesignInstance Type extensively as well. What I don't know how to do is declare the Type of the DataContext an ancestor. I found how to declare the type of the ancestor, but not the type of it's DataContext. My comment regarding religion was whether or not it was good design to have a User Control with it's own DataContext, rather than inheriting the DataContext of its parent, and, in my particular case, have a button in the UserControl bound to a command in the DataContext of the parent. To me that's completely fine. If there is a drawback I don't see it.

@PatriceBG d:DataContext is valid in design time only. Are you aware of the DataContext in run time?

@emoacht Yes, I understand that d:DataContext is design time only, I'm looking for an equivalent to specify the type of the DataContext of the parent. At run time everything works, as long as there is no typo in the name of the property.

@emoacht I would like to be warned at compile time if I refer to a non-existent property, e.g. a type. It's not a big deal, just a convenience. As I wrote before, if it can't be done I'll live with it.

"I would like to be warned at compile time if I refer to a non-existent property," --> "f there is a drawback I don't see it." - That's the major point: is impossible for a control to know the exact dates context. If you fix this by introducing a tight coupling to a particular type you are losing robustness, unless you start to throw exceptions when the DataContext has the wrong type. You lose the flexibility to use any data context as data source for your control. You violate a lot of common and valuable design principles like the open-close principle.

You can't change the data context type without breaking the control. This leads to all the known issues that every developer is afraid of. Issues that are extremely likely to turn against you sooner or later. And it's so easy to avoid. If you expose the required data via dependency properties you get it all: type safety (that's what's exclusively on your mind), proper decoupling of control internals and data context, which leads to a significantly improved maintainability and reusability or usability in general.

From a design perspective it really makes no sense to explicitly bind internals to the DataContext (if this involves the expectation of a particular type). Just imagine how useful such a ListBox would be that is only usable with a specific DataContext. I hope I could make it more clear why your approach to make the control to depend on a particular data type is a design smell that is so easy to avoid.

We can further say that if it is unavoidable that a control has to rely on DataContext implementation details, then chances are extremely high that this functionality either belongs to the view (more likely) or the depending functionality of the view belongs to the view model. As a side note, MVVM is an application level architectural design pattern. It's concerned with the strain of application level components like business logic.

It is not a class level design pattern. It did not say that every control is a view and has a view model. A control belongs to the application view and as such can reference a class of functionality of the application view model. MVVM also does not date about which programming language you use (XAML or C#/code-behind). Think about it: if you move UI code to a view model class to avoid code-behind (because you believe it is violating MVVM), didn't this really violate MVVM? Moving UI code from application view to application view model can never be a MVVM compliant solution.

Using dependency properties as data source and the DataContext only as client context for data binding those properties will give you compiler type checking (that's what your after) and a robust class design that values open-close, information hiding and other design principles.

@PatriceBG there is nothing wrong with your design. Please pay no mind to the fanatics here who can't answer a WPF question without a lecture about their design philosophy. Unfortunately no you can't achieve what you want. The VS editor simply isn't sophisticated enough to recognize the dctx of a relative source parent.

I may have spoken too soon. Mustafa's answer looks potentially like a promising alternative.

@EmperorEto Thanks, that's the straight answer I was looking for, if not the one I hoped for. And yes, Mustafa's answer does solve my main problem.

@PatriceBG a little off topic, but you might be interested - in MAUI you can specify the relativesource parent data context type without needing to know anything about the visual tree. It climbs the tree for you until it finds something with a dctx matching the type you want. It's close to my heart because it was my contribution to Xamarin Forms and intended for this very scenario :) Don't know if the MAUI editor extension is smart enough to recognize this and do the intellisense properly on the binding path, but it's certainly conceivable (and if not might be a PR they'd entertain).

@EmperorEto Thanks, that's good to know. One of those bits of information useful when choosing a framework for a new app.


I would like to be warned at compile time if I refer to a non-existent property
[See Comment]

#if DEBUG
    System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Switch.Level =
    System.Diagnostics.SourceLevels.All;
#endif

To open XAML Binding Failures go to Debug > Windows


Doesn't that only work at run time?

It works on both, I didn't expect that, Visual Studio got many improvements

That's an excellent alternative. It does not eliminate the squiggly blue underlines, but it does give the binding failures.

Glad it works! as a workaround, I hope you keep in mind the valuable information given by experts programmers in that long discussion, we will not find it anywhere, it requires years of hard working and knowledge

@Mustafa Oh please, Mustafa, I have over 50 years of experience in software development. I have learned the pitfalls and I know when my design is brittle. I have also learned when to apply the YAGNI principle. I didn't need a religious lecture on how to use WPF. Your answer was most appropriate and exactly what I needed to learn. I thank you for that.

Yeah Mustafa I agree with @PatriceBG. Not sure what you're getting at here but the bulk of the comments above are not helpful. Never mistake a huge # next to a name for wisdom or practical experience. It just means they have a lot more time to spend here than others. YOU provided a very useful tip that helped the OP and others who find this question in the future. The ... shall we say, vocal ... folks commenting above too often are more interested in evangelizing for their specific design philosophy (which is IMO highly misguided) than just answering questions as asked.

Also @PatriceBG 50 years??? Dang I thought I was old!

@EmperorEto/PatriceBG , All my respect to you and your words and years of experience, GBU

@EmperorEto, yeah, I'm celebrating this year the 50th anniversary of my Engineer Diploma in Computer Science from the University of Lille (France) and the 30th anniversary of my PhD in Computer Science from the University of Pennsylvania. And I still enjoy software design, development and learning new technologies, hopefully for a few more years. Hang in there, age doesn't mean much when you're still active and enjoying what you do.

@PatriceBG well hats off to you, Doctor! That delights me to hear. I likewise couldn't be happier to be where I am, but I do have those "kids these days..." moments more and more, especially on this site. Best to you, though, and if you have more WPF questions I'll be on the lookout, hopefully without igniting an all-out religious war, lol.

@EmperorEto Thanks, I appreciate that. Take Care!
